# Did Felix Leiter ever show up in the Brosnan era?

Tags: character, james-bond, cameo

Was there ever an actor in the Pierce Brosnan era of James Bond in the late 1990s, who played Bond's steadfast ally in the CIA, Felix Leiter, for even the quickest cameo?  By the first Brosnan film, *GoldenEye*, Bond is already relying on American agents who are separate characters, like Jack Wade, whom he's never met prior to the events of that movie.

Comment: I don’t have a solid source, but Goldeneye when written was supposed to star Timothy Dalton, and for continuity Leiter had lost his leg in one of the earlier Dalton movies, so maybe it made sense to keep him sidelined?

Answer (score 3):

No, [there was never a Felix Leiter in the Brosnan era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Leiter), most likely because of his removal from active service because of his missing leg. The reboot of the franchise with Casine Royale made it possible for Leiter to re-appear.